# Running Installutil to install a windows service on a shared folder

Tags: windows-services, installutil

-Hello,

I am trying to install a windows service from a shared folder like this:

```
installutil "\\\10.1.5.120\Path1\Path2\MyService.exe"
```

And having this error:

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\10.1.5.120\Path1\Path2\MyService.exe' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515).
```

There is no log at installutil log file and when i try to install service from a local path it installs successfully.

So i wonder is it possible to install a windows service on a pc from a shared path?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
<runtime>
   <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

in the installutil.config where the installutil.exe is at?

You can also try rightclicking the dlls and service exe -> properties -> unblock.

Comment: Thanks for providing this info

Comment: Man I spent a day just trying to get Fusion++ to tell me something.  This little trick needs to get scored higher!!!